# How to send request and response using http post url with body in android?

Tags: android, http, http-post

How to send `HTTP POST` request `URL` with `Body` and get responses using `HTTP POST` in android?

For Example
[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It varies depending of if you need to authenticate to see the webpage.

With or without the need of authenticating, you have to add the following permission in your Manifest to be able to access the webpage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In your activity or class that makes the access, you can do the following:

```
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

public class YourClass  
{
    BufferedReader intro=null;
    String url="Your Site URL?Your request body";
    DefaultHttpClient cliente=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","Your username"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","your password"));
    try
    {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpResponse response = cliente.execute(post);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)//this means that you got the page
        {
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            intro=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            intro.readLine();
            intro.close();
        }
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
    {

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
}
```

Finally,take into account this:

-If you are doing authentication,take into account the fields "username" and "password" (inside BasicNameValuePair) may have another name,which dependes on the webpage

-With intro.readLine of the BufferedReader, you are reading the webpage as if you're reading the file, so you may want to parse in order to avoid showing html code